# Overriding a plugin's function from another plugin/extended class

Tags: php, class, wordpress, overriding

I've got a "freemium" plugin, and I'm doing some major updates. Originally, users that bought the pro version would uninstall the free plugin, then install the pro version. Messy, but I was a beginner. So now I'd like users to be able to install the free plugin, then be able to install the pro upgrade that'll extend the functionality as planned.

My current plugin is using a class: class MyFreePlugin { __construct() ... } and my upgrade plugin is extending the class: class MyProPlugin extends MyFreePlugin { ... }

Here's my problem. I'd like to add functionality to the plugin's settings page and the tnyMCE popup window, as well as completely override some of the actions, filters and functions of the free version.

Example: the free plugin has

```
add_action('admin_head',array(&$this,'my_free_admin_head_fn'));
```

It adds/enqueues some scripts in the admin menu. I'd like to remove/override the original action and enqueue the scripts in the pro plugin:

```
add_action('admin_head',array(&$this,'pro_other_admin_head_fn').
```

Also, being new to php classes, especially in the context of WordPress, how can my extended class get the variable values of the parent?

Is all this possible, and if so, how? If you've got examples, that'd be even better. I've dug through the php manual, but it's not so helpful when trying to override filters and actions. Thanks for any help!

...
To counter your answer Janw, 
Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. Here's an example: In the __construct() of the free plugin, I have this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'add_plugin_menu'));
```

Which calls a function to add a menu to the admin sidebar. In my "pro" version of the plugin, I'm testing to see if I can remove that action before it fires with any of these:

```
remove_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'add_plugin_menu')); (nothing)
remove_action('admin_menu', array(parent,'add_plugin_menu')); (nothing)
remove_action('admin_menu', array(&parent,'add_plugin_menu')); (throws an error)
remove_action('admin_menu', 'parent::add_plugin_menu'); (nothing)
```

etc. Basically, the free plugin is loaded before the pro is, so the actions seem to be taking place before I can remove/override them. Plus, I'm unable to get to the parent's variables unless I make them all public, which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`remove_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/remove_action) to remove the functions your free version does.
And in the pro version you could only include the `MyFreePlugin` file and then extend.